# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable Error in Python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, compiler-errors, range

I have the following code:

```
x = [[],[]]
y = [[],[]]

for a in range(36):
    x.append[0](a)
    x.append[1](a)
for l in range(36,71,1):
    y.append[0](l)
    y.append[1](l)

z = x+y
```

For some reason it gives me this error:

```
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Not for "some reason". Because it's a method and you're trying to index it with `x.append[0]`. You want `insert` if you want to specify the index of where the values goes

Comment: @DhruvUpreti, you may also be looking to append to the first list of x. In such case, you'd want `x[0].append(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have mentioned why it failed, but I will add that if your goal is to achive the the lists of lists and combine them together, your corrected code of:

```
x = [[],[]]
y = [[],[]]

for a in range(36):
    x[0].append(a)
    x[1].append(a)
for l in range(36,71):
    y[0].append(l)
    y[1].append(l)

z = x+y
```

is a long-winded way of achieving that. It would be easier to eliminate the loops/appends altogether with, for example:

```
x = [list(range(36)), list(range(36))]
y = [list(range(36,71)), list(range(36,71))]
z = x+y
```

Or if you're running Python 3.8 and want to try out the new walrus operator to avoid calling the same `list(range())` twice:

```
x = [(rng := list(range(36))), rng[:]]
y = [(rng := list(range(36,71))), rng[:]]
z = x+y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't index the `append()` function. You can do that with the `insert()` function, however, like this:

```
list.insert(index, element)
```

`append()` has only one parameter, and it's the element that will be added at the **end** of the list.

```
list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x[0].append(a)
```

append is a method for list and is not subscript able..